# textbox related queries get all input details and calculate total amount

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
</head>
<body>
<section><b><b>

         <form action="" target="_blank">
         Bill No: <input type="text" name="bill no" size="">
         <input type="submit" class="button" value="Add">
         <input type="submit" class="button" value="Complete all entries">
             <br><br>
         Bill Details: <input type="text" name="bill no" size="50">
         <br><br>
         Amount: <input type="text" name="amount" pattern="[0-9]+" title="please enter amount"size="53">
             <br><br>
          <textarea rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
             <br><br>
         <label for="To Pay">To Pay:</label>
         <select name="mydropdown" id="To Pay">
         <option value="Director">Director</option>
         <option value="Cheif">Cheif</option>
         <option value="RPC">RPC</option></select>
         Cheque No: <input type="text" name="Cheque No">
         <br><br>
         Amount: <input type="text" name="amount" pattern="[0-9]+" title="please enter amount"size="15">
         Date: <input type="date" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" name="Dated">
         <input type="submit" class="button" value="Ok">
         </form>

  </article>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

## i want to crate a form in which i have two buttons on the top when i click on add button then it will be work as  bill ,details bill no and amount = textbox(textarea) then these all entry are shown in the textarea and add another entry that all are show as a tablewhen when i complete my all entries i click on complete all entries and than total amount off all entries are show on the bottom of textarea and this total amount automatically show in the bottom amount field. please suggest how can i do this task

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify your question?

Comment: have you done any ground work?

Comment: yes i done my ground work

Comment: i want if i enter bill no bill details and amount and click on add button these entries are show in the box that i given hear i dont know this type of box is suffieciant or not for this work may be its looks like a table that have bill no bill details and amount field and store my all given input and when i complete my all bills i click on another button and at the bottom of the table i found my total amount

Comment: this is like our shopping bills like when we purchase more than two items then we calculate total amount ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know the usage of jquery, so I use jquery to get the element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var total=0;
    var temp="";
    var tempResult=$("#tempResult");



    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        var billNo=$("#billNo").val();
        var billDetails=$("#billDetails").val();
        var amnt=$("#amnt").val();

        tempResult.val(tempResult.val()+ billNo + "-" +billDetails+ "-" +amnt+"\n");
        total+=parseFloat(amnt);
    });

    $("#btn2").click(function(){
         tempResult.val(tempResult.val()+ total);
        $("#totalAmount").val(total);
    });
});
```

And I change :

```
<input type="text" name="amount" pattern="[0-9]+" title="please enter amount"size="15">
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="amount" id="totalAmount" pattern="[0-9]+" title="please enter amount"size="15">
```

That all.

Comment: my project is done at this time all thanks to The KNVB if i want textbox store values like a table then what changes i made hear is it working hear or not.. like bill no have a column and all bill no goes in the rows below and same for other two fields and at the bottom have total amount column

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to give an id for every element for example:

```
<input type="text" id="billNo" size="">
<textarea id="tempResult" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
```

And then add function to capture the button click event.
Change the following HTML:

```
 <input type="submit" class="button" value="Add">
```

To:

```
 <input type="submit" class="button" value="Add" onclick="addEntry()">
```

after that add a function:

```
 function addEntry()
 {

 }
```

In this function,using the following coding to get the value of the element:

```
var billNo=document.getElementById("billNo").value;
```

Finally, using the following coding to write what you want to add to textarea:

```
var tempResult=document.getElementById("tempResult");
tempResult.value=billNo
```

For append value to textarea:

```
 tempResult.value+=*what you want to add to textarea*
```

To parse input value as an integer, you need to use parseInt function, for decimal no. you may use parseFloat function.

Now, you have all the ingredient to complete your function.

For the total amount, ha ha, let you try first.

Comment: my entry show once in the box and than disappear i dnt now why this happens when i work on jsfiddle and on stackoverflow than its perfectly run and add entries one by one but when i run this on google chrome than its like blinking

Comment: i write the code below as answer hear this is work properly but not working on browser

Comment: its works but move me on next tab but i want on the same page i add more bills how this happens....

Comment: Change <input type="submit" class="button" value="Add" id="btn1"> to <input type="button" class="button" value="Add" id="btn1">

Comment: i use this but when i add 2nd entry first one is gone only one entry is left in the box

Comment: but i need my all entries till now i click on complete my all entries what can i do

Comment: and please also provide me help regarding total amount at the end of the check box that calculate the total amount of all given entries

Comment: create a variable, say "total" and then add the amount to the variable when you add an entry to textarea ............